# How to check if an ApplicationUser has a Claim

Tags: c#, identity, claims-based-identity

Is it possible to check if an ApplicationUser has a Claim?

I know it is possible to check if an ApplicationUser is in a role

```
userManager.IsInRoleAsync(applicationUser,"admin");
```

And i know it could be possible to check if a user has a Claim like this:

```
userManager.GetClaimsAsync(applicationUser)).Any(c=>c.Type == "userType" && c.Vaue == "admin");
```

But i'd like to use something like with a ClaimsPrincipal object:

```
User.HasClaim("userType", "admin");
```

But i don't have a ClaimsPrincipal, i just have the ApplicationUser. So i also would like to know the way of getting the ClaimsPrincipal of an ApplicationUser, if it is possible.

Comment: You could write an extension method for the `UserManager`?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following extension method to your UserManager class:

```
public static bool HasClaim(this UserManager userManager, string type, string value)
{
    return userManager.GetClaims(applicationUser).Any(c=>c.Type == type && c.Vaue == value);
}
```

Now you can use this method on your `userManager` object:

```
var isAdmin = userManager.HasClaim("userType", "admin");
```

Comment: Where and what is applicationUser is the code snippet?

Comment: I figure the signature of the extension method would be:`static bool HasClaim<TUser>(this UserManager<TUser> umgr, TUser user, string type, string value) where TUser : IdentityUser`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jerodev answered you can use `UserManager` to get user claims. Alternatively, you can use your `DbContext` that is derived from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`.

```
bool hasClaim = _db.UserClaims
   .Any(c => c.UserId == userId && c.ClaimValue == claimValue && c.ClaimType == claimType);
```

Both techniques will work **only for claims that are stored in DB** and will not work for claims that you would add dynamically for example in `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`. Thus, both techniques are not the same as `User.HasClaim("userType", "admin")` where `User` is `ClaimsPrincipal`